# Cannot read property Connect of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Getting error `Cannot read property connect of undefined`  while making connection to mongodb using node js.
Following is my code:

```
var mongodb = require('mongoDB');
var mongoClient= mongodb.mongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

mongoClient.connect(url,function(err,clientObject){
    
     if(err){
          console.log(err);
     }
     else{
         console.log('connected successfully');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct below things,

- Correct mongoDB npm name to `mongodb`

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
```

- correct mongoClient class name to `MongoClient`

```
var mongoClient= mongodb.MongoClient;
```

Rest of the things are correct

```
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
mongoClient.connect(url,function(err,clientObject){    
     if(err){
          console.log(err);
     }
     else{
         console.log('connected successfully');
     }
});
```

Comment: Changing class name to MongoClient worked for me I think it's case sensitive